# How do I perform a query on a dynamic list of tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named as ( conntrack ) with unknown amount of tables.I have a static table "tabidx" which has one column "date".

The following table is static and its name is tabidx which provide reference to other tables:

```
 tabidx (table):
 +------------+
 |    date    |
 +------------+
 | 2015-04-25 |
 | 2015-04-26 |
 | 2015-04-27 |
 | 2015-04-28 |
 | 2015-04-29 |
 +------------+
```

The following are example to the referenced tables in 'tabidx' 'date':

```
2015-04-25 (table):                             
+---------------------------------------------+    
| time      | username | srcip      | scport  |    
+---------------------------------------------+    
| 19:20:00  | L001000  | 10.10.10.1 |  1304   |   
| 19:20:00  | L001001  | 10.10.10.2 |  1640   |    
| 19:20:01  | L001002  | 10.10.10.3 |  2001   |    
+---------------------------------------------+ 

2015-04-26 (table):                             
+---------------------------------------------+    
| time      | username | srcip      | scport  |    
+---------------------------------------------+    
| 19:21:00  | L001000  | 10.10.10.1 |  1304   |   
| 19:21:00  | L001001  | 10.10.10.2 |  1640   |    
| 19:21:01  | L001002  | 10.10.10.3 |  2001   |    
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to list to the manager the available tables that exists in tabidx and count how many users we have in all table if they are referenced in tabidx. So if the manager requested:

```
$_GET['fromdate'] = '2015-05-25'  
$_GET['todate'] = date(); //till today date 2015-04-30
$_GET['username'];
$_GET['srcport'];
$_GET['srcip'];
```

I would like the output to match mysql rows according to the requested above.
For example:

```
OUTPUT: [available tables WHERE username=L00100]
+-------------------------------------------+    
| Date and Time | username | srcip | scport |     
+-------------------------------------------+    
|   2015-04-25  | L001000  |   %   |   %    |   
|   2015-04-26  | L001000  |   %   |   %    |    
|   2015-04-27  | L001000  |   %   |   %    |    
+-------------------------------------------+
```

How can i list or select all tables that are found in the tabidx .? I dont know how to use prepared statements in mysql.

I know that the first step should be listing the available tables .
What if someone wants to requests the available tables that has specific user like "L002000" , then we should not list the tables at all because our dynamic tables dont have this username .

```
$db = new dB();

$_GET['fromdate'] = ( isset($_GET['fromdate']) && isValideDate($_GET['fromdate']) ) ?       $_GET['fromdate'] : $todayDate;
$_GET['todate'] = ( isset($_GET['todate']) && isValideDate($_GET['todate']) ) ?  $_GET['todate'] : $todayDate;
$sql_fromdate = " date >= '{$_GET['fromdate']}' AND";
$sql_todate = " date >= '{$_GET['todate']}'";

$result = $db -> query("SELECT date FROM tabidx WHERE $sql_fromdate $sql_todate");
$_GET['username'] = ( isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] !='' ) ?                           ....$_GET['username'] : '';


if($result)
{
    // Loop through the available tables that are included in table 'tabidx' 

    while( $b_row = $result -> fetch_assoc() )
    {
        $table_name = $db_row['date'];

        // Query the table and count the number of rows according to the requested $_GET Method

        $result2 = $b -> query("SELECT count(*) FROM $table_name WHERE username LIKE '{$_GET['username']}%'");
        $num_row = $result2 -> fetch_row();

        // Check if the number of rows are greater than zero
        // then show the row of $result to the user

        if($num_row[0] > 0)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>$table_name</td>';
            echo "<td>{$_GET['username']}</td>";
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

}
```

I have successfully made a temporary solution, but what i know that this solution is so bad, because we might reach up to 360 tables during a year.

Can we just do the whole work using one mysql query.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Why do you have a table for every date? Can you change your database structure and put all your data in 1 table and add a column for the date? Your tables are going to exponential grow in this current format.

Comment: Also, is your *$_GET['fromdate']* supposed to be *'2015-04-25'* not *'2015-05-25'*?

Comment: @Sean he/she is from the future...

Comment: I can not change the structure, because the external program "connection tracker program" inserts connection tracking data into table which is created dynamically according to the  day we are in.

Comment: each table might reach 649613 rows and more

Comment: $_GET['fromdate'] can be any date ... If we dont have that date that was requested then we show nothing or we show the available dates that we have as long as it is between dates that was requested by user.

Comment: The first step that i already did is :
$query = " SELECT date FROM tabidx "; we should list all the tables that are available in tabidx. But what if the user requested to see the aviable dates according to a specific user . That is a problem to me .

So we need to link or join the tabidx.date  with the dynamic table that is equal to tabidx.date . If the user is not found then dont show the date.

Comment: This is a terrible design. You have no chance of managing this schema successfully.

Comment: @Strawberry do u have a better design for logging daily traffic and store it in database plus allow others to search through these logs .? . Plus each table might reach up to million rows per day and up to 500 MB and maybe more . That was the only idea that i got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might help. We could get some information from the [schema table](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/understanding-the-mysql-information-schema-database.html) with a query like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE '*'
```

[mysq tables-table:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  [AND table_name LIKE 'wild']

SHOW TABLES
  FROM db_name
  [LIKE 'wild']
```

There might be some tables that may not be relevant to you, which I have not tried but by memory, this could be a starting point.

Hope this helps.